# Installing drivers with pnputil.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, drivers

For our workstation installation I have a batch script which detects the computer model and installs the needed drivers.

The first script contains this line:

```
[...]

call %path%\drivers.bat

[...]
```

The drivers.bat looks like this:

```
@echo off
%~dp0

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s *.inf') do pnputil.exe -i -a %%i
```

It's purpose is to install all inf-drivers it can find within it's folder.

If I doubleclick the drivers.bat it works perfectly fine. As soon as I call it from the first bat file I get an error message along the lines of:

> The command "pnputil.exe" is either misspelled or could not be found.

I tried to use

```
start /wait %path%\drivers.bat
```

but the result is the same.

Is there another way to call the script? Or is there a better way to execute pnputil.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

@Mofi pointed out that dpinst.exe is way better for installing drivers and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I strongly recommend not using `pnputil`, but use `DPInst32.exe` to install 32-bit drivers on 32-bit Windows or `DPInst64.exe` to install 64-bit drivers on 64-bit Windows. `DPInst` is the Microsoft Driver Package Installer. It is a free tool included in most driver packages of manufacturers really doing the driver installation (and not the GUI displayed installing additional software most often not really needed). Simply running for example `DPInst64.exe` from within a directory containing all driver files of a network adapter installs all of them. That's how Intel installs their drivers.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi . I tried it with DPInst.exe and it works like a charm.

Comment: One possible cause of this error is the batch file running in 32-bit mode for some reason.  Another is if the parent batch file is setting a value for `PATH` that does not include the system32 folder, although that's usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps try this

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s *.inf') do %SystemRoot%\System32\PnPutil.exe -i -a %%I
```

Additionally, to see where the PnPUtil executable is located, from `cmd.exe` run:

```
where pnputil
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I don't think PnPutil.exe is located under %SystemRoot%\System32\. Thanks anyway. I used dpinst.exe now and it works way better.

Comment: can you try this `do PnPutil -i -a %%I` by just removing path and `.exe`